# Powershell script running fine when running locally but when hosted on IIS server it is showing empty output

Tags: windows, powershell, flask, iis-7, iis-8

My script looks like this -

```
$Computer_Object = $args[0]
$Bitlocker_Object = Get-ADObject -Filter {objectclass -eq 'msFVE-RecoveryInformation'} -SearchBase " DC=XX,DC=XX,DC=com" -Properties 'msFVE-RecoveryPassword' | where-object   {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*$Computer_Object*"} | Select-Object -First 1
$Bitlocker_Object | ConvertTo-JSON
```

And i am calling this script in a flask server

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
#Getting the recovery key


def get_recovery_key():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data['systemName'])
    script_path="C:/inetpub/Bitlocker_Key/react-app/Backend/Script.ps1"
    command = ['powershell.exe', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Bypass', script_path]


    try:
        process = subprocess.run(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True) 
    # Capture standard output and error
        print(process.stdout)
        return {"output":process.stdout}
    except:
        return {"output":"There is some error in running query !!!"}
```

This is giving output when running locally but don't know how it is returning empty output string on IIS hosted site

```
{Output : ""}
```

Comment: There are a few key differences applicable to all web apps on IIS and the things they shell out (like your PowerShell script), https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: So how can we resolve this issue lex ?

Comment: If that PowerShell script does need to run as an individual user, not application pool identity, then you are out of hope. That's the burden to develop a web app instead of a desktop app, and why not every app is a web app.

Comment: You are making an HTTP request which get back a response.  Normal responses are 200 OK or a 400/500 Error.  If you are getting back a 200 OK than everything is working properly and if you are not getting any data than the query is is not finding anything in the database.  This usually means on the IIS server you are querying a different database than the one you are using locally.  Check the connection string to make sure you are connecting to the correct database.  The other possibility is the server is using a different version of the driver than locally.  The driver may be the issue.

Comment: Yes i am getting 200 ok response and also i have provided the permission to the account which i have used to host site on iis and using that account i run the same query on powershell it is giving me the correct output

Comment: It looks like a different connection string is being used.  Suspect the folder than is being used is different and the connection string is in a config file.

Comment: Try reading `stderr` - `Get-ADObject` might be throwing a non-terminating error

Comment: Is the AD module installed on the server where this will be running?

Comment: As an aside (it won't make a fundamental difference if the script path contains no spaces): Generally, use the `-File` CLI parameter for script-file invocations: `command = ['powershell.exe', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Bypass', '-File', script_path]`

Comment: Yes alexzelaya i AD module is installed on the server and yes mathias i have tried reading stderr but it was also producing empty result

Comment: Assuming you're showing us the complete script and in the absence of error suppression in the code (no `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` / `-ErrorAction Ignore` arguments, no `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`), it is implausible that you'd get _neither_ stdout nor stderr output.

Comment: So, you’re trying to query admin information from a remote client when you could do it locally from AD?

Comment: Cleary you have a permissions issue if you think a POST will be able to query those values from an AD object off the shelf…

Comment: @alexzelaya : What makes you think there is a permission error when you get empty results?  Without knowing the response status you are jumping to a conclusion without proof.  More often when no results are achieved the code is access a different database locally and deployed.

Comment: He’s querying AD for what seems to be an elevated property of any AD object. Also, where is the argument being passed in POST?